# gulp script and watch task

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I need some help, I've butchered what I had working while trying to add scss compilation and minification. I had scss working, but it made main.js not uglify. Then I switched some things and both don't work. This is my second day in Gulp, let alone .js.

**It's throwing an error on the line after the last line (which is blank?) and SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.**

Here's the code: (and thanks)

```
/* Required */
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

/* Scripts Task */
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src(['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/js/**/*min.js'])
    .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});

/* Watch Task */
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

/* Gulp-Sass Task */
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});
gulp.task('sass:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);

/* Default Task */
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'sass', 'watch']);
```

PS: Is there a better way of minifying my code that combines js and scss compiling?

Comment: You forgot `});` on the line before Default task comment

Comment: I've corrected that, however it is throwing an Error events.js:154 throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event

Answer (score 0):

You should use `gulp-scss` instead, I saw this when i visited `gulp-scss`'s page

> I found gulp-sass, but it doesn't seem to support actual sass, because the backend, node-sass is a port of libsass that has major limitations.

Also for minifying css why shouldn't you use `gulp-clean-css` ?

Comment: Let me work on checking that out. I should, however I'm a shiny brand new pet in this world :D

Comment: hehe.. sure! Hope it works! If it wont send me a fiddle of your gulpfile so i can check on it. :) @Corey

Comment: Arch, when I'm adding new watch tasks, are they completely new tasks or am i trying to gulp.watch again inside gulp.task?

Comment: Here is an example of my gulp watch task `gulp.task('allAssets', ['jade', 'stylus', 'jsx', 'svg']);  //this ends here..........................................
// watch task starts here ..................
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(
        ['assets/styl/*.styl', 'views/run/*.jade','assets/jsx/components/*.jsx', 'assets/jsx/*.jsx', 'assets/svg/*.svg'], ['allAssets']);
});
` you can check it from [here](https://github.com/maotora/react-boillerplatees2015/blob/master/gulpfile.js) around line `103 - 108` I make one gulp watch task and it checks all my files to run their tasks.

Comment: With just some hands on I figured out to create multiple watch tasks. Duh, watch is one of the main uses. Thanks for your help, getting js minified and my scss compiled by gulp-sass (was easier.) I guess it'll work for now

Comment: Sure, i just updated the comment above too including the link to my actual gulpfile.js

Comment: Hey Arch, one other thing: so I got my gulp task runner completely configured. Love it. Now, I'm easing into Node + Express. My question is: I can start the express server, then bash out my gulp task runner in another window...the express server runs index.js to port 3000, gulp runs my index.html on 3001. How can i merge these and use them together on the same port to begin development via html/css/angular? It is okay that gulp runs on a diff port? Will i be able to work on index.html and use angular/mongo etc with gulp and express running on diff ports? THANKS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110121/discussion-between-archnoob-and-corey).